# Find 3 letter words

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python:

```
import re
string = "what are you doing you i just said hello guys"
regexValue = re.compile(r'(\s\w\w\w\s)')
mo = regexValue.findall(string)
```

My goal is to find any 3 letter word, but for some reason I seem to only be getting the "are" and not the "you" in my list. I figured this might be because the space between the two overlap, and since the space is already used it cannot be a part of "you". So, how should I find only three letter words from a string like this?

Comment: @UlfGjerdingen if I understand OP correctly he wants to catch another **you** also

Comment: Yeah, but there is still one "you" missing. I added another "you" in the string, only so I could try if the overlapping space was the problem. Which it seemed to be, so the output should be 2 "you".

Answer (score 8):

It's not regex, but you could do this:

```
words = [word for word in string.split() if len(word) == 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use word boundary `(\b\w{3}\b)` if you strictly want to use regex otherwise, answer suggested by Morgan Thrapp is good enough for this.

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7YnHc5L0_7VydOSJ)

Comment: And this syntax is indeed supported by Python (which the link doesn't seem to directly demonstrate.) This is the best regex-based solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

`findall` finds non-overlapping matches. An easy fix is to change the final `\s` to a lookahead; `(?=\s)` but you'll probably also want to extend the regex to cope with initial and final matches as well.

```
regexValue = re.compile(r'((?:^\s)\w\w\w(?: $|(?=\s))')
```

If this is not a regex exercise, splitting the string on whitespace is much mose straightforward.