# Python: Scanning a file for a (3 letter) word

Tags: python, file, words, alphabet

I don't even know how to go about scanning a file (line by line) for a word (with 3 letters) in a logical way, that will let me set a suggested (3 letter) word as a variable (or maybe something better for me to call upon later?).

With that variable, I would first have the program verify with me that it is a 3 letter word.

I am a beginner in python, so I am not very efficient with my coding. I made a python file that is 150+ lines of code that doesn't work. If you would like me to add it just comment and I will add the whole file to this page. I have already looked at the link [[Find 3 letter words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728006/find-3-letter-words][1])
but it didn't help me with what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: What's wrong with the link? How doesn't it help you? Just read your file line by line and extract 3 letter words and put em in a list.

Comment: `words = [word for line in string.split() if len(word) == 3]` folllow this after you read the files and iterate through `lines`. Its the non `regex` approach as suggested in the link you have mentioned @Ethan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    words = [word for word in line.split() if len(word)==3 ]
print(words)
```

Comment: How would I then take each word from the new list I have and export them to a new file (each word has its own line).

Comment: @EthanMcRae So, you have to write the word into the corresponding line as original file?

Comment: No, I would want to write each word from 'words' to a file called 'words3.txt'

Comment: for that First open the file `words3.txt` `with open("words3.txt",'w') as w` and then use `for` loop to write like this: 
    `for item in words:`
         `w.write("{}\n".format(item))`

Sorry for the wrong indentation.
Above approach will write `words` item in new line in `words3.txt`
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks for your continuous help!